# Correlation of one binary input series and continous response series

Tags: time-series, arma, binary-data, cross-correlation

I have one input series of type 0/1 (it is an intervention time series) and some metric response series. I need to have a look at cross correlations. Normally I would use Box-Jenkins-technique. But now I have to prewhiten an input series which is binary. Can I handle it like a metric one? Does it make sense to look at the autocorrelations and fit an ARMA-model in the "normal" way?

Or would it be possible to fit ARMA-models for the metric response variables and then fit the same model to the input variable and then look at the cross correlations?

Nearly all of my response series are white noise - but as I understand I have to fit an ARMA-model to the input if this is not white noise anyway. Is this correct or is it sufficiently for the response to be white noise?

Would be very happy if anyone can help me!
Thank you very much.